# Service is stopped by Android

Tags: android, service, ondestroy

I am running and unbounded service (no activity, because the activity was just for collecting data) an it seems, that the service is stopped by Android if a memory consuming programm runns (I use JellySplash for that.. :) ). Therefore I use shared preferences only if the service ist destroyed by the system, to get the data again when the Service is created again:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    if (stopSlf==false) {
        Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        String strKZ  = kennzeichen;
        editor.putString("strKZ", strKZ);
        editor.commit();
        stopSlf=true;
    }
    Log.e("Destroy", "Destroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

This seems to work, but as you can see in the LogCat, onDestroy is not called before the system destroyes the service (and I think the 3 cryptic "D lines" mean, that the service ist destroyed):

```
02-17 20:59:43.626: E/onCreate(19183): onCreate
02-17 20:59:43.636: I/Pref AnzAlarm(19183): No Pref data
02-17 20:59:43.651: I/Alarmmanager(19183): CancelAlarmMainActivity
02-17 21:00:04.096: I/Anzahl Alarme(19183): 1
02-17 21:00:15.026: I/Anzahl Alarme(19183): 2
02-17 21:00:25.286: D/ActivityThread(19835): handleBindApplication:com.fifteen
02-17 21:00:25.291: D/ActivityThread(19835): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
02-17 21:00:25.291: D/ActivityThread(19835): setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
02-17 21:00:25.536: E/onCreate(19835): onCreate
02-17 21:00:25.576: I/Pref AnzAlarm(19835): No Pref data
02-17 21:00:25.611: I/Alarmmanager(19835): CancelAlarm
02-17 21:00:25.636: E/Stopself(19835): StopSelf
02-17 21:00:25.651: E/Destroy(19835): onDestroy
```

So you can see, the code calls onCreate after the "3 lines", but there is no "onDestroy" before the 3 lines - therefore my sharedpreferences are never stored.

Why??

Thanks a lot!

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
if(stopSlf==false)
```

to

```
if(stopSlf)
```

should work.

Comment: if (!stopSlf) is of course more elegant, but it does not change, that onDestroy is not called by the system, when it destroys the service. stopSlf is a variable, that is true, when I stop the service in the code [this.stopSelf();]

Answer (score 0):

As when an Activity is killed rather by the system or the user, you won't receive the onDestroy callback. A way to prevent this to happen you can call the `startForeground()` and `stopForeground()` methods to let the OS know that the service must be alive as long as possible. If you are strongly dependent from the data in the Service or it's not autogenerated, then you will need to save it constantly on any modification to be restored later when the service is started again.

Comment: startForeground() is a good tip, thanks! Beside that, you mean, I should use sharedpreferences anywhere in the code, but not in onDestroy? That could also work, thanks!

Comment: Yes, you should save those preferences everytime the data has changed. Waiting for onDestroy() to be called in this particular case will only help you if you explicitly call stopService()/stopSelf() methods so you are aware that the service will be destroyed